# Formatting a disk drive

Tags: command-line, prompt

I need to get to the c prompt before windows 8 loads.  I want to reformat my hard drive and reinstall windows 8 because I cannot get it to recognize my password.

Comment: I would just boot to a Windows 8 installation disk.  There hasn't been a concept of a `c prompt` since Windows ME.

Comment: You can easily hack the password of windows 8. You dont have to whipe your disk.

Answer (score 3):

You **don't have to format your computer**, because you've forgot your password. You can reset your password by using this little "hack".

I'm sorry for the bad enumeration. If I change it, than it will begin from 1 everytime i interrupt the list. [Here is the well-looking-tutorial.](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/reset-password-windows-8.htm)

> 1.Access Advanced Startup Options. In Windows 8, all of the important diagnostic and repair options available to you can be found on the
>   Advanced Startup Options (ASO) menu.
>
> **Important**: There are six ways to access the ASO menu, all described in the link above, but some are only available if you can
>   already get into Windows 8, which you can't do since you don't know
>   the password. I recommend following Method 4, which requires that you
>   have a Windows 8 setup disc or flash drive, or Method 5, which
>   requires that you have, or create, a Windows 8 Recovery Drive. Method
>   6 works too, if your computer supports it.
>
> 2.Touch or click on Troubleshoot, then Advanced options, and finally Command Prompt.
>
> 3.Now that Command Prompt is open, type the following command:
>
> `copy c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe c:\`
>
> ...and then press Enter. You should see a 1 file(s) copied
>   confirmation.
>
> 4. Next, type this command, again followed by Enter: copy c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe Answer
>      with Y or Yes to question about the overwrite of the utilman.exe file.
>      You should now see another file copy confirmation.
>
> 5.Remove any flash drives or discs that you may have booted from in Step 1 and then restart your computer.
>
> 6.Once the Windows 8 logon screen is available, click the Ease of Access icon at the bottom-left corner of the screen. Command Prompt
>   should now open.
>
> What?! Command Prompt? That's right! The changes you made in Step 3 &
>   4 above replaced the Ease of Access tools with Command Prompt (don't
>   worry, you'll reverse these changes in Step 11). Now that you have
>   access to a command line, you can reset your Windows 8 password.
>
> 7.Next you need to execute the net user command as shown below, replacing myusername with your user name, and mynewpassword with the
>   password you'd like to begin using:
>
> `net user myusername mynewpassword`
>
> For example, on my computer, I would execute the command like this:
>
> `net user "Tim Fisher" a@rdvarksar3skarY`
>
> Note: You only need to use double quotes around your username if it
>   happens to have a space in it.
>
> Tip: If you get a The user name could not be found message, execute
>   net user to see the list of Windows 8 users on the computer for
>   reference and then try again with a valid username. A System error
>   8646 / The system is not authoritative for the specified account...
>   message indicates that you're using a Microsoft account to login to
>   Windows 8, not a local account. See the Important call-out in the
>   introduction at the top of this page for more on that.
>
> 8.Close Command Prompt.
>
> 9.Login with the new password you set in Step 7!
>
> 10.Now that your Windows 8 password has been reset and you're back in, either create a Windows 8 password reset disk or switch your local
>   account to a Microsoft account. No matter which you choose, you'll
>   finally have legitimate, and much easier to use, Windows 8 password
>   reset options.
>
> 11.Finally, you should reverse the hack that makes this password reset trick work in Windows 8. To do that, repeat Steps 1 & 2 above.
>
> Once Command Prompt is open again, execute this command:
>
> `copy c:\utilman.exe c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe`
>
> Confirm the overwriting by answering Yes and then restart your
>   computer.
>
> Note: While there's no requirement that you reverse these changes, it
>   would be irresponsible of me to suggest that you don't. What if you
>   need access to Ease of Access from the logon screen someday? Also,
>   please know undoing these changes won't undo your password change so
>   don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to wipe your whole HDD, you could just boot to the installation CD/DVD and Windows 8 installer has an option to delete your partition and recreate the partition - and allows you to re-install windows.